# Adding a scope for admins if there is only one model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I'm using Devise gem in Rails app. Instead of creating 2 model (for Users and Admins), I created only one named Users with an attribute is_admin.

Now I want to add scope in my `routes.rb`. Will I be able to do this? I can't do the following since I have only model:

```
namespace 'admin'do 
  devise_for :admins #:users
end
```

So how can I add a scope for `admins`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to give a detailed answer without knowing more about your setup, but I would suggest that both users and admins could log in through the same forms and whether a user sees the admin functionality could just be taken care of by something like CanCan. So there wouldn't be any need to do `devise_for` twice.